# Why does my router broadcast a ghost SSID at the same frequencies and strength with my defined SSID?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

With Huawei H122-373 with the latest software and the 5G Wi-Fi network, it broadcasts into two different SSIDs at the same strength, one of them my original SSID and the other with no name.

Resetting the modem several times has not helped.

Using apps like [(Wi-Fi overview-analyzer)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUpM5.jpg) to search about wifi networks the two SSIDs overlap exactly over each other.
Again the two SSIDs at the same frequencies with the same strength but with different names, and I'm sure that both come from my router.

One I defined the other was broadcasted by the router with no name .
Is it normal that the modem broadcast a noname SSID?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 6):

Probably a **mesh backbone**. If you were to install compatible mesh access points, they would use this hidden network to communicate.

Comment: I don't need to use the Huawei H122-373 as base for a Wi-Fi Mesh network. can I simply turn the noname SSID off?

Comment: I don't know - there's no full manual on Huawei's website. Check the management panel for mesh-related stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced both my modem and router and started afresh with a new network name, but the old network kept popping up and was even connected to the Internet. After two months of searching and unplugging devices, I discovered a Ubiquiti Unify repeater installed years ago and plugged into an ethernet port. It was programmed with the old network name and password. Unplugged it and the ghost was exorcized.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).